# Chrome app create new window in fullscreen - html element is not full height

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-app

I have an issue where I'm creating a new window in fullscreen mode, but the content within that window doesn't end up taking up the full screen. The html element ends up being something like 83px in height. I want it to take up the full size of the window since I have a certain background color, etc. set on it. I'm creating windows in a similar manner in other places of the app, and it works fine, but in this specific instance it doesn't. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

This is the code used to create the window:

```
chrome.app.window.create('connectionError.html', { id: 'connectionError', state: 'fullscreen'}, function() {
    chrome.app.window.get('connectionError').fullscreen();
});
```

And this is the html of the resulting page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <meta charset='utf-8'>
      <title>Connection Error</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/application.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="js/connectionError.js"></script>
  </head>


  <body>
    <div id="connectionErrorContainer" class="container">
        <div id="connectionError" class="col-md-12">
          <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; float:none;">Unable to connect. Please check your internet connection.</div>
        </div>
        <button id="restart" class="btn btn-primary">Restart</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't post your CSS so I don't know for sure, but I'd bet this is what you're missing: `html,body,#your-element { height: 100%; }`

Alternatively, if you're only targeting chrome, you can simply add `height: 100vh` to your element.

Comment: The only css for that page was a background color for the body. I guess I just assumed that the html element would take up 100% of the window height. I was wrong, haha. Adding the height 100% to html, body and the container did work.

Comment: "if you're only targeting chrome" Yes, that is what Chrome Apps usually are for...